# How do I ensure that a date is in this format: MM-DD-YY including dashes

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I'd like to validate a date to be in this format: MM-DD-YY (including dashes). How do I do this in PHP (or JavaScript)?

Comment: You could start by using split('-') and check the digits are within the expected range. i.e: 12, 31, 99

Comment: By the way, please don't. This isn't at *all* a standard format and is confusing for anyone outside your country.

Comment: @Gareth - Why not? It's standard for the US?

Comment: I'm giving instructions that it should be MM-DD-YY format, I just want to make sure it is before I put in DB

Comment: @Andypandy You wont be able to correct/validate human error if the user enters 01-04-12 actually meaning 01 Apr 2012. If they miss/don't read the instruction.

Comment: @WilliamIsted best to use drop downs and construct manually...

Comment: @Andypandy Yes, Giving the user less option for user error. Being in the UK with the date format DD-MM-YY I'm fairly often entering the wrong date on websites.

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
function isValidDate(date)
{
    var matches = /^(\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})$/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var d = matches[2];
    var m = matches[1] - 1;
    var y = matches[3];
    var composedDate = new Date(y, m, d);
    return composedDate.getDate() == d &&
            composedDate.getMonth() == m &&
            composedDate.getFullYear() == y;
}
console.log(isValidDate('10-12-61'));
console.log(isValidDate('12/11/61'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$d = "02-05-20";

if(strlen($d) == 8 && checkdate($d[0].$d[1],$d[3].$d[4],$d[6].$d[7]))
{
    echo "Valid Date";
}
```

Checks wether the string is correctly formatted and the date itself is valid.

- `02-05-20` validates `true`
- `13-05-20` validates `false` (no thirteenth month)
- `2-5-20` validates `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate_date($string) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-j-y', $string);
    if ($date === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $dateparts = explode('-', $string);
    if (!checkdate($dateparts[0], $dateparts[1], $dateparts[2])) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; // You can also make this return $date if you want to use it further
}

var_dump(validate_date('02-28-99')); // true
var_dump(validate_date('02-29-99')); // false
```